# how to access questions ramdomly from sqlite?

Tags: java, android

i am building an quiz app i want to retrieve 10 questions randomly from 100 question in database.

here is the code from where i am retrieving question from  database

```
QuizDbHelper dbHelper = new QuizDbHelper(this);
            questionList = dbHelper.getQuestions(difficulty);
            questionCountTotal = questionList.size();
            Collections.shuffle(questionList);
```

QuizDbHelper class getQuestions method:

```
 public ArrayList<Question> getQuestions(String difficulty) {


    ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    db = getReadableDatabase();
    String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{difficulty};
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE " +QuestionsTable.COLUMN_DIFFICULTY+"= ?", selectionArgs);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Question question = new Question();
            question.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION)));
            question.setOption1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1)));
            question.setOption2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2)));
            question.setOption3(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3)));
            question.setOption4(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION4)));
            question.setAnswerNr(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR)));
            question.setDifficulty(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_DIFFICULTY)));
            questionList.add(question);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    c.close();

    return questionList;
}
```

when i run this all the 100 questions are appering 
anyone to fix it better..

Answer (score 0):

First Retrieve all questions from database in Arraylist of Question

then shuffle your arraylist.

```
Collections.shuffle(questionList);
```

and sublist to 10 like

```
   questionList.subList(0,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your function as

```
 public ArrayList<Question> getQuestions(String difficulty,int size,boolean random) {


     ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{difficulty};
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE " +QuestionsTable.COLUMN_DIFFICULTY+"= ?", selectionArgs);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question question = new Question();
                question.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION)));
                question.setOption1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1)));
                question.setOption2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2)));
                question.setOption3(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3)));
                question.setOption4(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION4)));
                question.setAnswerNr(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR)));
                question.setDifficulty(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_DIFFICULTY)));
                questionList.add(question);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        c.close();
    if(random)
      Collections.shuffle(questionList);

    if(size > 0 && size < questionList.size()){
      Collection<Question> collection = questionList.subList(0, size)
      ArrayList<Question> subList  = new ArrayList<>();
      subList.addAll(collection);
      return subList;
     }

        return questionList;
    }
```

Comment: error has occured  ' questionList=  questionList.subList(0,size);'  incompatible types: List<Question> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Question>

Comment: change the questionList (ArrayList<String> ) to ArrayList<Question>

Comment: sorry, my bad updated the code now it should work without any problem.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList$SubList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: @GaneshGudge ,@KundanSingh